# Get row count of table component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get the row count of a table component in vuejs. I need the row count outside the table component. The below code (obviously) doesn't display the right row count in the `<h>` tag (and crashes the page since data is an unknown variable at this point).

Should I use `$emit`?

```html
<h v-html="'Items (' + this.data.length + ')'"></h>

<vs-table :data="dataArray">
  <template slot="thead">
        <vs-th sort-key="itemName">Items</vs-th>
    </template>

  <template slot-scope="{data}">

    <vs-tr :data="tr" :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data">

      <vs-td  :data="data[indextr].itemId">
        <b>{{ data[indextr].itemName }}</b>      
      </vs-td>

    </vs-tr>

    </template>

</vs-table>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        dataArray: [{
          itemId: 0,
          itemName: 'some name 1'
        }, {
          itemId: 1,
          itemName: 'some name 2'
        }]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: I just added data source to the code

Comment: How about `<h v-html="'Items (' + dataArray.length + ')'"></h>`?

Comment: This works (It was my default solution). My table however has a searchbox which filters results without affecting dataArray. So if the table is filtered the count of items on display will be incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You do not use `this`in Vue templates.  Every variable in a Vue template has an implicit `this`.

```
<h v-html="'Items (' + dataArray.length + ')'"></h>
```

```
<h v-html="`Items (${dataArray.length})`"></h>
```

If dataArray is null or undefined at mount, use a v-if.

```
<h v-if='dataArray' v-html="'Items (' + dataArray.length + ')'"></h>
<div v-else>Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As have been mentioned before there is no need to use **`this`** in template syntax to get the values of reactive data (properties).

Another way to do this using a **`computed property`** that would return the `length` of the table data at any point. And use that in the template.

**At Script:**

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dataArray: [
        {
          itemId: 0,
          itemName: "some name 1"
        },
        {
          itemId: 1,
          itemName: "some name 2"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    tableLength: function() {
      return this.dataArray.length;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**At Template:**

```
<h v-if='dataArray'>Items {{tableLength}}</h>
```

OR

```
<h v-if="dataArray" v-html="'Items ' + tableLength"></h>
```